# Getting the Text of an EditText outside of the main activity

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception

I just got into developing Android apps with Kotlin and run into the following Problem:
I wanted to build a small login just for fun.
I kinda figured that that is due to me trying to get the Text via `v.findViewItemById()` but can't find another way/a way to go around it
But when executing the App crashes on me with the error
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference`

My MainActivity.kt: (removed imports)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    private lateinit var B: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        B = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(B.root)


        val btnListener = ButtonClickListener()
        B.btnLogin.setOnClickListener(btnListener)
    }
}
```

And the ButtonClickListener.kt:

```
package de.fynnhenck.login.listener

import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import de.fynnhenck.login.MainActivity
import de.fynnhenck.login.R
import java.security.AccessController.getContext

class ButtonClickListener : View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        val bu = v as Button
        val loginText = v.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_loginText)
        val username = v.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_username)

        val password = v.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_password)

            if(username.text.equals("user") and password.text.equals("pass")){
                loginText.text = "Test"
            }
    }
}
```

I hope this explains my issue well enough.
Thank ya'll for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `findViewById` of your `View` (`btnLogin` is your case), it tries finding between descending views. So since `tv_loginText` is not child view of your button, this row

```
val loginText = v.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_loginText)
```

sets `loginText` to `null`.

Try accessing your textviews via binding:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    private lateinit var B: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        B = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(B.root)


        val btnListener = ButtonClickListener()
        B.btnLogin.setOnClickListener(btnListener)
    }

    class ButtonClickListener : View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            val bu = v as Button


            val loginText = B.tvLoginText // LIKE THIS
            ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That sounds reasonable.
I'll try this one.
Thank you for your explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe its crashing because onClick(v: View?) only contains view of your button and not your 2 other editText and thats you are getting null.

Why two files and not directly adding this logic in MainActivity?

```
B.btnLogin.setOnClickListener {
   if(B.username.text.equals("user") && B.password.text.equals("pass")){
      B.loginText.text = "Test"
    }
 }
```

Comment: That would make sense...
I tried to make it in a different class due to organisation. This one will do it :) ty